# Правильное использование PIVOT в MS SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, pivot

У меня есть запрос с кучей лефтджойнов.

Создала запрос для вывода "прямых" данных, выводит:

```
|Номер заказа|Атрибут   |Значение|
|9213        |Формат    |20х20   |
|9213        |Количество|4       |
|9213        |Материал  |кожа    |
|9214        |Формат    |80х80   |
|9214        |Количество|1       |
|9214        |Материал  |дерево  |
```

Мне нужно отобразить следующим образом:

```
|Номер заказа|Формат|Количество|Материал|
|9213        |20x20 |4         |кожа    |
|9214        |80x80 |1         |дерево  |
```

Вообще не понимаю, как ПРАВИЛЬНО описать pivot, все примеры какие-то слишком простые, а у меня запрос 5 джойнами и 6 условиями. Можете, пожалуйста, на этом примере показать и описать..

Comment: WITH temp (Номер заказа, Атрибут, Значение) AS (запрос 5 джойнами и 6 условиями) SELECT ... FROM temp PIVOT ...

Comment: Номер заказа, Атрибут - это всё без кавычек вводится? А в селекте что писать? Не понимаю, как эти названия вводить полей

Comment: *Номер заказа, Атрибут - это всё без кавычек вводится?* Поскольку это имена полей, тем более кириллицей да с пробелами - обрамить квадратными скобками. *А в селекте что писать?* То же, что и в "каком-то слишком простом примере", как если бы temp была реально таблица из 3 полей, а не замороченный запрос.

Comment: Тогда следующий вопрос, в структуре PIVOT-а обязательно надо писать функцию типа MAX(), COUNT() итд. Но у меня значения VARCHAR, как быть?

Comment: MAX() и MIN() ничего не имеют против параметров типа VARCHAR...

Comment: Спасибо. Всё равно не понимаю смысл этим макс и мин...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот вам работающий пример:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_table ([Номер заказа] int, [Атрибут] nvarchar(250), [Значение] nvarchar(250));

INSERT #temp_table
VALUES
(9213,N'Формат',N'20х20'),
(9213,N'Количество',N'4'),
(9213,N'Материал',N'кожа'),
(9214,N'Формат',N'80х80'),
(9214,N'Количество',N'1'),
(9214,N'Материал',N'дерево');

WITH temp AS 
(SELECT * FROM #temp_table) -- сюда вставьте ваш запрос, как указал коллега

-- ниже, по сути, все что вам нужно

SELECT [Номер заказа],[Формат],[Количество],[Материал] 
FROM temp 
pivot
(
max([Значение])
for [Атрибут]
in ([Формат],[Количество],[Материал]) 
)
as pvt

DROP TABLE #temp_table
```

Документация: [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: А что есть "TempValue", откуда он взялся?

Comment: @АминаКирова Это ваше "Значение", не зря же я вам дал полностью работающий код, с созданием и заполнением временной таблицы.

Comment: Это супер, спасибо. Но я пытаюсь понять и не могу. Объясните, пожалуйста, "SELECT orderid [Заказ],[Формат],[Количество],[Материал]" - что это?

Comment: @АминаКирова поправил под ваши столбцы, разбирайтесь. Лучше всего прочтите документацию, и придумайте себе еще пару задач

Comment: Спасибо за уделенное время.